# Computing total sum of word frequency by using pthreads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I am running three threads and trying to computer total frequency of each word.
I need put mutex to protect from counting issue.

```
57848 index is 0
37389 index is 1
8447 index is 2
10016 index is 3
2756 index is 4

The results are counted as follows : 
he -> 57848
she -> 37389
they -> 8447
him -> 10016
me -> 2756



void threadfunc(char *path, char *filetowrite, long specialfreq[], int num_threads){

  DIR* dir = opendir(path);
  if(dir == NULL){ return; }
  struct dirent* entity;
  entity = readdir(dir);

  
  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    if (pthread_join(thread_id[i],  NULL) != 0) {
      perror("Failed to join thread");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `defalut:`. This isn't the actual code. Who knows how many other transcription errors there might be. Always copy/paste the exact code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threads are reporting the values of `data->freq[i]`, which is shared among all threads.

To count locally in each threads, you should first create local counters for each threads before the loop:

```c
long threadCounter[SPECIALSIZE] = {0};
```

Then, count using this counter instead of `data->freq`:

```c
        while(tkn != NULL){  
          if((strcasecmp(tkn, "he") == 0)){
            threadCounter[0] = threadCounter[0]+ 1;
          }else if((strcasecmp(tkn, "she") == 0)){
            threadCounter[1] = threadCounter[1]+ 1;
          }else if((strcasecmp(tkn, "they") == 0)){
            threadCounter[2] = threadCounter[2]+ 1;
          }else if((strcasecmp(tkn, "him") == 0)){
            threadCounter[3] = threadCounter[3]+ 1;
          }else if((strcasecmp(tkn, "me") == 0)){
            threadCounter[4] = threadCounter[4]+ 1;
          }
          tkn = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
```

(note: `threadCounter` is local to this thread, so no lock is required for updating counter)

And finally report the value of the counter and add that to `data->freq`:

```c
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    printf("%d index is %d\n", threadCounter[i], i);
    data->freq[i] += threadCounter[i];
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Also note that the function `strtok()` is not thread-safe (cannot be called from multiple threads simultaneously). Therefore, `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);` should be added before `char* tkn = strtok(line, " ");` and `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);` should be added before `}fclose(fp);` for correct processing.

Comment: Is there any way that I don't use strtok ? it seems taking so much time to run

Comment: @user19603927 You can use [`strtok_r()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) if it is available in your environment.

Comment: Also I added lock and unlock but it seems taking forever, could you please edit my code to show correct position for putting them please ?